# Loopback: Send request with json data using REST connector

Tags: json, node.js, rest, datasource, loopback

I would like to fetch data from 3rd party REST Service in my Loopback Application. In order to fetch data from Service I need to authenticate first with login and password. I can test service using curl:

```
curl -b cookies -c cookies -X POST -d '{"auth": {"username":"MyUser","password":"Secret"}}'  'http://api.awesome.service.com/'
```

That works great. Tcpdump shows request like that:

```
Host: http://api.awesome.service.com/
User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
Accept: */*
Cookie: HBFAPI_SESSID=hbapi%3A197887%3A58a3028d12c36%3Anym2
Content-Length: 58
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

{"auth":{"username":"MyUser","password":"Secret"}}
```

So, I've created datasource first:

```
{
    "awesome_datasource": {
    "name": "awesome_datasource",
    "baseURL": "https://api.awesome.service.com/",
    "crud": false,
    "connector": "rest",
    "operations": [{
        "template": {
            "method": "POST",
            "url": "http://api.awesome.service.com/auth",
            "form":{
                 "auth": {
                     "username": "{username:string}",
                     "password": "{password:string}"
                 }
            },
            "json": true
        },
        "functions":{
            "login": ["username", "password"]
        }
    }]
  } 
}
```

I tested that using explorer. No matter what I do, I can't get data in request body formatted as json. With or without json option result is this same, which in tcpdump is:

```
host: api.awesome.service.com
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
accept: application/json
content-length: 66 
Connection: close

auth%5Busername%5D=MyUser&auth%5Bpassword%5D=Secret
```

I've tried pass parameters as 'query', 'form' or 'data' option. Also checked various header content-type options, but no luck so far.

Model is simple without parameters. Base model is 'Model' (no User, because I want to keep it simple as possible)

I was able to find this thread, but it wasn't much help:

```
https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-rest/pull/12
```

Any advice will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well all you have to do is to use `json` instead of `form` there:

```
{
    "awesome_datasource": {
    "name": "awesome_datasource",
    "baseURL": "https://api.awesome.service.com/",
    "crud": false,
    "connector": "rest",
    "operations": [{
        "template": {
            "method": "POST",
            "url": "http://api.awesome.service.com/auth",
            "json": {
                 "auth": {
                     "username": "{username:string}",
                     "password": "{password:string}"
                 }
            }
        },
        "functions":{
            "login": ["username", "password"]
        }
    }]
  } 
}
```

REST connector tries to mimic [request module](https://github.com/request/request) as much as possible. Basically `body`, `json`, `form` and `query`(`qs` in request) do the same thing as the request options but they also accept template strings. Here's the documentation from request with a little modification:

- `query`(`qs` in request) - object containing querystring values to be appended to the `uri`
- `body` - entity body for PATCH, POST and PUT requests. Must be a `Buffer`, `String` or `ReadStream`. If `json` is `true`, then `body` must be a JSON-serializable object.
- `form` - when passed an object or a querystring, this sets `body` to a querystring representation of value, and adds `Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header. When passed no options, a `FormData` instance is returned (and is piped to request). See "Forms" section above.
- `json` - sets `body` to JSON representation of value and adds `Content-type: application/json` header.  Additionally, parses the response body as JSON.

Comment: I knew about body, query and form. I just didn't know about json. Thanks. It almost work but replace placeholders with null's:

     {"auth":{"username":null,"password":null}}

I solved it ealier by using 'body', but I must pass values as:
    {
        "username": ...,
        "password":  ...
    }

which is a bit uncomfortable.